# Custom Upload Status Web Part

Tags: development, web-part, web-services

Looking to create the following scenario:

Weekly a client will access their SharePoint site to upload a specified number of files. (for example 5 files) We are looking for a solution that will prior to the user uploading the documents it will display in our example 5 red bars signifying the documents are not uploaded. Once a document is uploaded the red status bar will turn to green. At the end of each week we would like to send a notification to a specified group on the number of files that have been uploaded.

Initially I was thinking that a separate SharePoint list would need to be created with 2 columns. 1) Client Name 2) Number of files to be Uploaded. We then would have to create a connection maybe through the Web Service to say:

[image]

Is there some type of sandboxed solution or event handler that can satisfy these requirements?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint do you use as the development platform? Have you looked into Document Sets in conjunction with workflows?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603637(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: We use SharePoint 2013 Standard edition. No we haven't used document sets.